# UIStepper on IOS 5

Tags: ios5, uistepper

I can't use UIStepper to take value from UITextfield to increment or decrement stepper.value please help me with this problem.
My code:

```
 -(void)stprPressd:(id)sender
 {
 float a=[textField.text floatvalue]

 [stepper setMinimumValue:0];
 [stepper setContinues:YES];
 [stepper setWraps:YES];
 [stepper  setStepValue:1]

 textField.text=[NSString stringWithFormat@"%f",stepper.value]
 stepper.value=a;
 stepper setMaximumValue:10];   
}
```

Comment: Does variable a get the value from textfield?

Comment: try with this if u get value of a:[stepper setContinuous:NO];

Answer (score 0):

I think you are setting the control properties in its change event. You should initialize and set the control properties into `viewDidLoad` method.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

// Frame defines location, size values are ignored
UIStepper *stepper = [[UIStepper alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 20, 0, 0)];    

// Set action target and action for a particular value changed event
[stepper addTarget:self action:@selector(stepperPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

[stepper setMinimumValue:0];
[stepper setMaximumValue:10]; 
[stepper setContinues:YES];
[stepper setWraps:YES];
[stepper  setStepValue:1]
[self.view addSubview:stepper];
[stepper release];
}
```

And your `stepperPressed:` method should look like this

```
-(void)stepperPressed:(UIStepper *)sender{
 textField.text=[NSString stringWithFormat@"%lf",sender.value]
}
```